# Why does fmt.Fprintf with an http.ResponseWriter not work for a css file?

Tags: go, http, webserver

When I serve a css file like so:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {

  b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("style1.css") // 7626 bytes
  bigString := string(b)

  http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css")
    writer.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(bigString)))
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, bigString)
  })

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))

}
```

and I curl http://localhost:3000/ I get:

`curl: (18) transfer closed with 7626 bytes remaining to read`

but if I just change the fmt.Fprintf like to:

`writer.Write([]byte(bigString))`

it works fine. This took me hours to debug, my css file would not load right all because of fmt.Fprintf.

Comment: oh i think I see why https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.1:src/fmt/print.go;drc=b94dc384cabf75e7e8703265cd80f5324f84b642;l=1021 there are things in there that css syntax will trigger!

Comment: If you don’t want the first argument to be used as a format string, use `Fprint`, not `Fprintf`

Answer (score 1):

https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Fprintf

This will look for stuff like %s or %d and try and do normal printf stuff!

With a css file I had % chars in it and they were missing from the end result or causing the curl transfer closed.